# Sort multi-dimensional array, append text and then continue to sort array by number value in javascript

Tags: javascript, sorting, multidimensional-array, alphanumeric

My current code for sorting a multi-dimensional array:

```
s.storeValues = [];

convertToArray: function(e){
   var xVal = Math.floor(e.offsetX / s.pixSize) * s.pixSize;
   var yVal = Math.floor(e.offsetY / s.pixSize) * s.pixSize;

   s.storeValues.push([xVal, yVal]);
   var compare = function(a, b) {return a[0] - b[0]; };
   s.storeValues.sort(compare);
}
```

The issue is when I try to add (in order to add px to number + mimic css box-shadow syntax)

```
for(var i = 0; i < 2; i++){
   s.storeValues[s.storeValues.length - 1][i] += "px";
}
```

The sort no longer works. Any ideas on how to proceed from here, is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Above code all together (for reference):

```
s.storeValues = [];

convertToArray: function(e){
   var xVal = Math.floor(e.offsetX / s.pixSize) * s.pixSize;
   var yVal = Math.floor(e.offsetY / s.pixSize) * s.pixSize;

   s.storeValues.push([xVal, yVal]);
   var compare = function(a, b) {return a[0] - b[0]; };
   s.storeValues.sort(compare);

   for(var i = 0; i < 2; i++){
     s.storeValues[s.storeValues.length - 1][i] += "px";
   }
}
```

Edit: I would like to keep "px" appended to array value, after number is parsed and sorted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add pixel, you have strings and not numbers. So you need to parse out the number

```
convertToArray: function(e){
   var xVal = (Math.floor(e.offsetX / s.pixSize) * s.pixSize) + "px";
   var yVal = (Math.floor(e.offsetY / s.pixSize) * s.pixSize) + "px";
   s.storeValues.push([xVal, yVal]);
   var compare = function(a, b) { return parseFloat(a[0]) - parseFloat(b[0]); };
   s.storeValues.sort(compare);
}
```

Comment: Hmm, maybe it's code on my end, but it is now appending "px" when I click on a value smaller than the initial value. In addition, at that time, it starts appending "px" to old values, creating a snowball effect. –

Comment: Because you are adding px to the last element, when it is sorted it will not always be the last one!